# Is it safe to call YUI.add for the same module more than once on the same page?

Tags: javascript, yui, portlet

I am working in a portal environment.  I want multiple portlets to use some common YUI modules.  I also want to have the portlets be 100% self contained.  In other words, I don't want to have to put the YUI.add call in a universal JS at the portal level.

So, each porlet has a copy of the same JS code (added by the build process from a common dependency, I don't *manually* keep the code in sync across portlets).  If more than one portlet is on the same page, this would mean the YUI.add would be called by each.  Is this going to cause problems?  I could probably put all the JS in a separate servlet and let the YUI dynamic loader take care of it, but this would bring back in an external dependency.  In order for these portlets to work, the servlet would have to be deployed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YUI keeps track of modules that it has already loaded:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/yui_js_yui.js.html#l568

Everytime you call `YUI.add(` on a module it loops through YUI instances and checks to see if they have loaded the module yet. If the instance hasn't loaded the module, the `add` method offers the module to the instance's loader.

So there is a tiny overhead in redundantly calling `add`, but it's not serious.

Comment: thanks, that was how I read the code as well, I was just worried that the `env.mods[name] = mod;` on line [560](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/yui_js_yui.js.html#l560) was blindly adding the new module definition to the `YUI.Env` global object without checking if it was already defined.  Is it safe to assume there are no negative side effects to this?

Comment: @Lucas As long as all of your redundant calls to `add` are identical, I don't see any negative side effects. It's just assignment~ so even smaller overhead than the loop through YUI instances.

Comment: so they have to remain identical...  thats what i thought.  Though it makes things a little more difficult as now if a portlet gets updated with a newer version of that module, all other portlets on that page will also have to be updated since it puts the definition in by name and ignores version number...  not as portable as i would like, but seems to be i have no choice.  Guess I could check YUI.Env myself before calling add, but that seems like something that should be in the framework...